# How do I remove login password for Centos6.5?

Tags: login, password, centos, autologin

### Question 1

On `Centos 6.5`, I have a username called `admin`.  How can I make it so the system logs in automatically?

### Question 2

How can I configure system to login as `root` user when there are other users on the system?

Please don't bother me with security risks as this is a testbed station.  There is no sensitive information that I need to worry about.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Question 1:
Just edit `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` with your favorite editor. Then, under the [daemon] section, add 2 lines so it looks like the code below (change username to the username you want to use):

```
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=username
```

Comment: Thanks @ryekayo. Is there man page for `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` that I can look at for other configurations?  If so what would I type?

Comment: I am looking for other options as well as the man page, that may not work for CentOS 6.5. Please bear with me.

Comment: Can't find a manpage on it. It's funny because I am running CentOS 6.5 on my VirtualBox and I can't find that directory. Yet I have looked up numerous resources and it insists that thats the way to do so. But then again I only have the minimal.iso file for CentOS

Comment: Thanks for everything! It turns out if you set `AutomaticLogin=root` the system will actually login to as `root` user.  So you actually resolved both my questions.  Did you at least find this solution on CentOS website?

Comment: I did not, I saw multiple resources stating the same thing though, the `custom.conf` file would need to be changed in order to get it set up as you mentioned. One website in particular seems to deal with CentOS based questions: http://centos-base.blogspot.com/2014/01/autologin-with-centos-65.html

Comment: Great thanks--It would have been nice to see what other options and features which could be set in this file...

Comment: If I see anything, I will add to my answer :)

Comment: If you don't mind upvoting, I'd be highly appreciative :)

Comment: I upvoted your question my friend